# Contribute without delete permission level and Connect to Outlook

Tags: 2010, permissions, discussion-board

I know that I can create Contribute without delete permission level.

Now suppose I create a discussion board and give users this permission level. When they connect this list to Outlook, they are still able to delete the item in their Outlook.

What happens in this scenario ? Will the item not get deleted from SharePoint?

I am using sharepoint 2010.

Comment: Just try it out and get back to us! This is an interesting question

Comment: I tried it, but I am getting confusing results. It gets deleted from outlook, but not sharepoint. And then if I sync again, nothing happens. Ideally, it should again sync back to Outlook.

Comment: Maybee Outlook have somehow the item saved as deleted, and hence ignores it on an new sync